# mysql joining tables without show duplicate data

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join, inner-join

I want to select all data from my table revistas and the matched values from other tables without duplicate data.

This is a image of my database
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31988662/a.png

I want to export data exactly as follows, all idrevistas with all matched ids from other tables

```
idrevistas  idsentido_efeito   idamostra       idnatureza_efeito  idfatores_afeta_efeito
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1              1                1,2,3              1                   1
  2              2                2                  2                   2
  3              1                2,3                1,2                 2
  4              2                1,2                4,5                 2,1
```

The closest I could get was a simple join like this:

```
SELECT rev.nome_revistas,se.nome_sentido_efeito, rev.titulo_revistas, rev.subtitulo_revistas_autor_ano, rev.abstract, group_concat(ams.nome_amostra),se.nome_sentido_efeito,group_concat(ne.nome_natureza_efeito),  fae.nome_fatores_afeta_efeito
FROM revistas_has_amostra as rha
JOIN revistas as rev ON rha.revistas_idrevistas = rev.idrevistas
JOIN amostra as ams ON rha.amostra_idamostra = ams.idamostra
JOIN sentido_efeito as se ON rev.sentido_efeito_id = se.idsentido_efeito
JOIN revistas_has_natureza_efeito as rhne ON rev.idrevistas = rhne.revistas_idrevistas
JOIN natureza_efeito as ne ON rhne.natureza_efeito_idnatureza_efeito = ne.idnatureza_efeito
JOIN revistas_has_fatores_afeta_efeito as rhfae ON rev.idrevistas = rhfae.revistas_idrevistas
JOIN fatores_afeta_efeito as fae ON rhfae.fatores_afeta_efeito_idfatores_afeta_efeito = fae.idfatores_afeta_efeito
GROUP BY rev.idrevistas
```

But that returns matches in the amostra_id table multiple times as below

```
idrevistas  idsentido_efeito       idamostra       idnatureza_efeito  id_fatores_afet..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1              1                1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3    1,1,1             1
   2              2                2                    2                 2
   3              1                2,3,2,3              1,2,1,2           2
   4              2                1,2,1,2              4,5,4,5           2,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `DISTINCT` to all the `GROUP_CONCAT`

i.e.

```
SELECT rev.nome_revistas
    ,se.nome_sentido_efeito
    ,rev.titulo_revistas
    ,rev.subtitulo_revistas_autor_ano
    ,rev.abstract
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ams.nome_amostra)
    ,se.nome_sentido_efeito
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ne.nome_natureza_efeito)
    ,fae.nome_fatores_afeta_efeito
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add GROUP BY amostra_id?

```
GROUP BY rev.idrevistas, rev.amostra_id
```

Comment: I've already tried to add GROUP BY rev.idrevistas, ams.amostra_id and doesn't take effect. thanks for your answer